# app crashed on CLClientStopVehicleHeadingUpdates

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, crash-reports, ios12

Any idea why the app is crashed, from the below logs unable to find the reason for crashing.

Crash logs:

[image: getting]

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue( as I am also facing the same issue)?

Comment: any update on this issue.

Comment: @AnshulBhatheja, I didn't found any solution for this yet. I got this issue for only one time.